# Help me solve B\A and complement of A

Tags: calculus

> $A = (1,2)\cup(3,4) ; B=[1,4]$
>   find $B\setminus A$ and the complement of $A$
>
> also is $A\setminus B=\emptyset$ right ?

Comment: It might help to realize that A is a proper subset of B. Also, your answer for A\B is correct as everything in A is also in B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$B\setminus A=\{1\}\cup[2,3]\cup\{4\}$

$A^c=(-\infty,1]\cup[2,3]\cup[4,\infty)$

$A\setminus B=\emptyset$

Answer (score 0):

- $B \setminus A$ is read as "B (set minus) A", which means: "Remove from B all the elements of B that are also in A". Whatever is leftover is your answer for $B \setminus A$

For your example:

$B\setminus A$ = $[1,4] \ (1,2)U(3,4) $ = ${1}U[2,3]U{4} $

This is because:

B is a closed set (it includes 1 and 4) and A is the union of two open sets. Then you remove all the points between 1 and 2 from B but leave 1 and two themselves. Same goes for 3 and 4. And there is also the obvious gap between 3 and 4 in A and so all those points stay.

---

- $A \setminus B$ = {} Because B "covers" A. You could also say because $A \subset B$

---

$A^c$ means the complement of A.

A complement is always relative to another set. We could discuss the complement of A relative to B or the complement of A relative to the universal set. So if $\mathbb{R}$ is the universal set and we take $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}$, then we have a different complement.

I assume you want the complement of A relative to $\mathbb{R}$. Then:

$A^c= \mathbb{R}\setminus A = (-\infty,1] U [2,3] U [4,\infty)$

And you can now see that: $A U A^c = \mathbb{R}$

And in general that the union of a set and its complement should be equal to your relative set. (So if you want $A^c$ relative to B then $A^c U A = B$)